# Easy way to check whether there is data pending in istream

Tags: c++, io, iostream

Is there any standard, non-reading way to check if there is any char pending in the input stream? I can always try something like

```
char buffer[256];
std::cin.get(buffer, 256, '\n');
if (!std::cin.fail()) {
// use buffer
}
```

but it condemns me to playing with ios flags, using C-strings and so forth. Isn't there any simpler, cleaner way to do it? Like this:

```
if (std::cin.has_data()) {
    std::string data;
    std::getline(std::cin, data);
    // do my stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The function [peek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) is the solution.**

As said by the cppreference:

> If good() == true, returns the next character as obtained by
> rdbuf()->sgetc()
>
> Otherwise, returns Traits::eof().